# Marking a class as final vs ease of testability?

Tags: java, unit-testing, final

Most of the classes in our team are marked as `final` going by the idiom if the class isn't designed for inheritance prohibit it. I get that part of it but how do I test such classes? I can use `PowerMock` but that is discouraged as well.

The other option is to have an API and implementation but that seems like an overkill for internal classes. I was just wondering how people approach this problem?

Edit: Here is the psuedo-code.

```
public final class ServiceDiscovery
{
  private final Environment env;

  public ServiceDiscovery(final Environment env)
 {
   this.env =env;
  }

public String getService()
 {
  //Processing logic
   String x = env.getEnvironment();
   // Process x
  return x;
  }  
}

public class Environment
{ 
  public String getEnvironment()
  {
    // Perform logic to get environment
    String env = callFunction();
    return env;
  }
}
```

How to mark `Environment` as `final` here? It needs to be mocked when I'm testing `ServiceDiscovery#getService()`.

Comment: What are you trying to test that requires you to create a subclass? Normally you'd mock the dependencies, not the class itself - and if all those dependencies are expressed via interfaces or abstract classes, you can fake those regardless of whether the real implementation is final or not. It would help if you'd give a representative example in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: @Jon I don't need to create a subclass but I want to test the methods inside the class without having to use PowerMock or using the interface, implementation approach. Another option is to create a factory wrapper class but that seems like an overkill again.

Comment: so your team seems to be making a point that it doesn't want you to write tests? or they want you to use an interface separate from the impl class and you're resisting?

Comment: With the rise of unit testing, it has become clear that the extensive use of final classes is a bad practice because it inhibits mocking.

Comment: @Nathan I do feel it's an overkill to use interface, implementation for internal classes.

Comment: From what you've described that's your only option, though. when you're on a team sometimes it's best to go along with the agreed-on conventions.

Comment: If your want to test the class itself, why are you mocking it? Again, a complete example would make it easier to understand...

Comment: @DwB: I don't think that is clear at all. I think the rise of unit testing has highlighted the need for clear separations of concerns and dependencies, mind you...

Comment: Yet a final class 'inhibits' mocking of that class.  That seems like a bad practice to me.

Comment: Forbidding mocking is a _great_ practice for classes that are inappropriate to mock, like any sort of value type, collections, and many more.  Most classes shouldn't be mocked at all.

Comment: @Jon The class is being used in another class which is being tested and needs to be mocked there. For example, assume that we've a Person instance passed into an Employee class and we want to test Employee but Person needs to be mocked and can't be marked final.

Comment: At that stage it sounds like you've *currently* got a tight dependency from `Employee` to `Person`, which is only suitable if you're happy to use the actual implementation in `Person` (no mocking required) - or you want to treat the `Person`'s API as a dependency, in which case extracting an interface makes sense, IMO.

Comment: @DwB: I'd say that it prevents you from making too tight a dependency - it allows you to keep using the class if the implementation is fine to use in tests (as Louis says) and firmly encourages you to use an abstract class or interface where you really *don't* want that implementation.

Comment: @Jon The thing is that the actual implementation in Person is making a database call which I don't want to do, hence the thought to mock.

Comment: Right, so that sounds like it's probably a design / separation of concerns issue.

Comment: @Jon Are there any good sources to read to better design these things? I have skimmed through Effective Java and Head First Design Patterns and I've heard good things about the Gang of Four. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Not really - I've mostly learned through experience. I'd warn against dogma in almost any form though...

Comment: Robert Martin (aka Uncle Bob) has a lot of material online and multiple books published that discuss SOLID principles and design patterns. maybe parts of these border on what @Jon calls dogma (some agile rah-rah) but they seem largely helpful to me. Definitely Effective Java is worth more than a skim.